# Dynamic Google hosted DNS zone update by DHCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns-zone, isc-dhcp

I have dns zone running in Google Cloud.
I would like to integrate my ISC-DHCP with that zone by enabling automatic host registration into the zone.

I'm looking for some analogy to enable in Google Cloud this BIND feature:

```
   key DHCP_UPDATER {
     algorithm HMAC-MD5.SIG-ALG.REG.INT;
     secret pRP5FapFoJ95JEL06sv4PQ==;
   };

   zone "example.org" {
        type master;
        file "example.org.db";
        allow-update { key DHCP_UPDATER; };
   };
```

and configuring the DHCP server to update the zone on the lease changes.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work, most cloud providers don't allow you to update DNS records they host via that kind of interface. You'd need to find some kind of plugin or tool that mirrors the changes via their cloud APIs.

Your best option is to delegate a subdomain and allow that to be updated via DHCP, hosted in the same environment that will be querying it.